# XDG_ 系の環境変数とは？

Tags: unix

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes を見ていました。

そこで、もし $XDG_CONFIG_HOME の環境変数が設定されているならば～のような記述があったのですが、この環境変数はみなれていないので、これは何なのかと思っています。

質問:

- XDG_ 系の環境変数とは何ですか？

  - どのような環境だと設定されている変数ですか？
  - どのような設定を表す変数ですか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

X11上のデスクトップ環境を標準化しているfreedesktop.orgプロジェクトが規定している環境変数です。GNOMEやKDEをはじめとするデスクトップ環境で設定されます。

それぞれの環境変数の意味は[XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)を参照。